# flutter_playout android:exported needs to be explicitly specified for element <receiver#tv.mta.flutter_playout.audio.RemoteReceiver>

Tags: android, flutter, manifest, video-player, androidexported

I am using https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_playout package.

I am facing this error in Android while iOS is running file.

```
/Users/jeckymodi/Documents/Projects/biblicaltrainingflutter-development/android/app/src/debug/AndroidManifest.xml:33:9-37:20 
    
android:exported needs to be explicitly specified for element <receiver#tv.mta.flutter_playout.audio.RemoteReceiver>. 
Apps targeting Android 12 and higher are required to specify an explicit value for `android:exported` when the corresponding component has an intent filter defined. 
See https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element#exported for details.

/Users/jeckymodi/Documents/Projects/biblicaltrainingflutter-development/android/app/src/debug/AndroidManifest.xml:33:9-37:20 
Error:
    android:exported needs to be explicitly specified for element <receiver#tv.mta.flutter_playout.video.RemoteReceiver>. 
Apps targeting Android 12 and higher are required to specify an explicit value for `android:exported` when the corresponding component has an intent filter defined.
See https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element#exported for details.
```

Here is my manifest file.

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.biblicaltraining.flutter">
<application
    android:label="BiblicalTraining"
    android:name="${applicationName}"
    android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"
    android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/launcher_icon">
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:exported="false"
        android:launchMode="singleTop"
        android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
        <!-- Specifies an Android theme to apply to this Activity as soon as
             the Android process has started. This theme is visible to the user
             while the Flutter UI initializes. After that, this theme continues
             to determine the Window background behind the Flutter UI. -->
        <meta-data
          android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme"
          android:resource="@style/NormalTheme"
          />
        <receiver android:name="tv.mta.flutter_playout.audio.RemoteReceiver" android:exported="false" />
        <receiver android:name="tv.mta.flutter_playout.video.RemoteReceiver" android:exported="false" />

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <provider
        android:name="vn.hunghd.flutterdownloader.DownloadedFileProvider"
        android:authorities="${applicationId}.flutter_downloader.provider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/provider_paths"/>
    </provider>
    <!-- Don't delete the meta-data below.
         This is used by the Flutter tool to generate GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java -->
    <meta-data
        android:name="flutterEmbedding"
        android:value="2" />
</application>

<!-- Set permissions -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Please let me know what I am missing